# common practice for testing an application with javascript client-side

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, integration-testing

I need to automate E2E testing for a web application. The front-end of the application is implemented using a JavaScript framework and the back-end is Java technology. I know there are tools/frameworks available for JavaScript testing. I'm wondering if I can use Java (such as java with selenium-webdriver) for my tests. Is it a common practice?

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can.
Please do some research about using Junit / NGtest for automation testing on web apps